# Android maps design change

Tags: android, fragment, android-mapview, android-design-library

Is it posible to make design adjustments to android Fragment, so that maps look like this?

[image]

Comment: See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104325/how-to-use-custom-map-tiles-with-the-google-map-api-v2-for-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, youll need to add something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/map_white_overlay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where @drawable/map_white_overlay will be your white fade image. Ask designer to get it from his psd or try to get it yourself somehow.

As for map style, from google-play-service 9.6.0 you can style your map using this [link](https://hackernoon.com/using-custom-styles-with-google-maps-android-api-e1e5ec3ac7e9#.oaerjfy4c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/) instead of Google maps. Then you can customize your map.

Comment: not exactly what I need, I need to customize my layout that I have right now with android native resources, animations, blurs, colors, etc...

Comment: post your layout and expected layout as image.

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible. I think what you need can be done all in the layout XML (that you can use in your own subclass of `Fragment`), something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/mapView2"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/some_9patch_drawable_with_white_sides"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:text="Search text here"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="Your actions down here"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think the hardest part will be creating a 9-patch drawable with white sides to emulate what I think your map looks like, but totally possible.

Comment: hey man, thank you for your answer. I tought to do something similar to this, I just need to know what is the name of the effect I want to achieve(the white fade)?

Comment: as far as I know there is no out of the box solution to achieve the white fade effect (that I know about), but a background 9-patch drawable that is drawn above the `MapView` in the `FrameLayout` will work (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)